# Threading is not working in parallel - Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a question related to threading in python.
I am running 8 threads using for loop in the main(). In my actual code, the task of each thread is to find a specific pattern in the text string to a specific length which is defined. it will create a new list to store the results and apply different functions to that list and append a list of lists which is in the main function (test list in this case). Now, i have tested in on a single thread and it takes around 4.0 secs. Apparently, the other threads (if work in parallel) should be completed in 5 or 6 secs at max ( All 8 threads ). But it is taking 42 seconds.  i am appending the results in the list test (in this case).
Just an example if its helps.

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    modules=8
    test=[]
    threads=[]
    time1=time.perf_counter()
    for i in range(modules):
        p1= threading.Thread(target=testfunction,args=(i,test))
        p1.start()
        threads.append(p1)
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
    time2=time.perf_counter()
    print(time2-time1)
```

Comment: [python global interpreter lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) prevents that, instead you should use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).

Comment: also it's wrong to create a thread for every task, instead you should reuse threads by using a [threadpool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor) or multi-processing pool, as creating a thread is accompanied by a large overhead.

Comment: Did you try using a pool method instead? I am not sure how the different threads are joined with each other in your second for loop

Comment: @Neo
Yes, i have tried ThreadPoolExecutor but it takes the same time which is 42 secs.

Answer (score 0):

CPython has a concept called a "global interpreter lock" that means only one thread at a time can be executing Python code.  Thus, Python threading only works with I/O-intensive code that spends most of its time sleeping or waiting for I/O.  Compute-intensive operations do not gain from threading in Python.